# JSON.NET Object Deserialisation with class

Tags: c#-4.0, deserialization

I am using these classes:

```
public class MasteryPages
{
    internal MasteryPages() { }

    [JsonProperty("pages")]
    public List<MasteryPage> Pages { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("summonerId")]
    public long SummonerId { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MasteryPage
{
    internal MasteryPage() { }

    [JsonProperty("current")]
    public bool Current { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("talents")]
    public List<Talent> Talents { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Talent
{
    internal Talent() { }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rank")]
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code I'm using to deserialise the object

```
//MASTERIES
var jsonMasteries = requester.CreateRequest(string.Format(RootUrl, Region) + string.Format(MasteriesUrl, summonerId));                       
var objAllMasteryPages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MasteryPages>(jsonMasteries);
```

The jsonMasteries object is correctly serialized and gives me this:
http://pastebin.com/3dkdDHdx (Rather large, to view easily: go to http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and paste it)

The second line is giving me troubles however. Normally my object should be filled with the data. It unfortunately isn't and I have no idea what's wrong.

Anyone could help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this part of serialized JSON: `"42177333": { ... }`

As I understand - this is some kind of ID and it's dynamic. 
Possible solutions are:

- One of possible resolutions is here: [C# deserialize dynamic JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504805/c-sharp-deserialize-dynamic-json)
- Cut this part of dynamic JSON.
- Try to modify the serialization stuff to avoid this dynamic ID.

Comment: Thank you, this one slipped trough my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sleepwalker I saw what was wrong. (Dynamic Id (number), first line)

Now, the James Newtonking JSON library has a solution for dynamic id's like this. 
I edited my code to this:

```
var jsonMasteries = requester.CreateRequest(string.Format(RootUrl, Region) + string.Format(MasteriesUrl, summonerId));
var  objAllMasteriePages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<long, MasteryPages>>(jsonMasteries).Values.FirstOrDefault().Pages;
```

(First line stays the same, the magic is in the second line)
Now, i use a dictionary with the key being my given Id, and my custom class.

This works wonders