# Deserialize Json into a C# dynamic object using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json

I have the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771804/how-can-i-deserialize-a-child-object-with-dynamic-numeric-key-names) in that I want to deserialize *dynamic json data*. In other words, the keys: "error1, etc are dynamic. In my case:

```
{
    "errors" : {
        "error1" : {
            "name"  : "connection error",
            "location" : "CPU board",
            "id"    : "E0001"
        },
        "warning2" : {
            "name"  : "Value not formatted",
            "location" : "Controller",
            "id"    : "W005"
        },
        "info4" : {
            "name"  : "Attention to temperature",
            "location" : "Heater",
            "id"    : "I008"
        }
    }
}
```

In the question, the answer uses `JsonConvert` to deserialize into a dictionary. I have found also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505176/4451521)  that something similar can be done using `JavascriptSerializer`.

I suppose that I can use those to solve my problem but my question is, can I do this too using `DataContractJsonSerializer`?

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize it simple as dictionary of objects:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Error>(json);
```

Implement a class like the following:

```
public class Error
{
  public class Details
  {
    public string Name {get;set}
    public string Id {get;set}
    public string Location {get;set}
  }
  public Dictionary<string, Details> Errors {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. How about doing it using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Comment: You need to use DataContract and DataMember attributes in your class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data

Comment: I mean how to do the above with DataContractJsonSerializer (I know DataContract is required)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
    Error deserializedError = new Error();
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedError.GetType());

    deserializedError = ser.ReadObject(ms) as Error;  
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that Error is the class of your object.  If not, then just replace Error with your class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the object data like `errors.error1.name etc..` then consider using `dynamic` and `ExpandoObject`. Here is a working example

```
using (var f = new StreamReader("json1.json"))
{
    string json = f.ReadToEnd();
    dynamic deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(deserializesObject.errors.error1.name);
}
```

Output: `connection error`

I hope this helps.